# replace() and replaceAll() in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

The following code uses the `replace()` method of the `String` class in Java.

```
String a = "abc/xyz";
System.out.println(a.replace("/", "\\"));
```

`/` in the given String `a` is being replaced with `\`.

The same thing is wrong, if we use the `replaceAll()` method as follows.

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("/", "\\"));
```

It causes the exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown. It requires two additional backslashes `\` like the following, since `replaceAll()` uses a regex which is not the case with the `replace()` method.

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("/", "\\\\"));
```

The only question is why does this method when used with only two slashes like this `a.replaceAll("/", "\\")` throw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

---

The `split()` method on the other hand initially issues a waring `Invalid regular expression: Unexpected internal error` (I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1).

```
String b="abc\\xyz";
System.out.println(b.split("\\")[0]+b.split("\\")[1]); //Issues a warning as specified.
```

An attempt to run this causes the exception `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` to be thrown.

Since it uses a regex like `replaceAll()`, it requires four back slashes.

```
System.out.println(b.split("\\\\")[0]+b.split("\\\\")[1]);
```

Why does `a.replaceAll("/", "\\\\");` as in the preceding case not issue such a warning or such a run time exception, even though it has an invalid pattern?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If this is for a filename, leave it be, it will work as is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Javadoc [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\")));
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this method when used with only two slashes like this
>   a.replaceAll("/", "\") throw
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

As you know, `\` is a metacharacter in regex. When you use `\` in regex, it is always followed by another character e.g. `\d or \s`.

Your `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception is coming when it tries to evaluate the **pattern string ITSELF** i.e. `\\` and **it doesn't find a following character, which is mandatory in this case.** This is not coming on the argument string `a` --> abc/xyz as It tries to do below:

```
if (nextChar == '\\') {  //<-- \\ is read here
    cursor++;

    //<--Its attempting to read next character and fails
    nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor); 
    result.append(nextChar);
    cursor++;
}
```