# Adding Escape parameter to a String is not working

Tags: java

Current value of the String is

```
^I am Shaikh with "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$
```

My code is as below:

```
System.out.println(strAnnotationValue); // prints ^I am Shaikh with "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$

strAnnotationValue = strAnnotationValue.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
System.out.println(strAnnotationValue); 

Actual Output:   ^I am Shaikh with "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$
Expected Output: ^I am Shaikh with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$
```

---

I have written the proper code but it is not working, is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Just a friendly notice:  if the code you have doesn't work, there's a very good chance that the code you've written isn't correct.

Comment: Take a look at this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556101/java-replace-all-in-a-string-with

Answer (score 1):

If yours is a perfect code then you will get the expected output right??

Do one thing replace your this line

```
strAnnotationValue = strAnnotationValue.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

with this

```
strAnnotationValue = strAnnotationValue.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\\"` means `\"`,when it output,it will be display: `"`

so do like this: `\\\\"`

`\\\\"` means `\\"`,when it ouput, it will be diaplay:`\"`

```
strAnnotationValue = strAnnotationValue.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation star :)